# Settings.bundle Swift 5

Tags: xcode, swift5

I am using the settings.bundle in swift 5 and would like to observe changes from the default settings and update the app without restarting it - what is the best way to do this?

```
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["String" : "Any"])
        let defaultValues1 = ["btn1_name": "Name your Btn 1"]
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: defaultValues1)
        let btn1value = ["btn1_onoff": true]
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: btn1value)
        
        let defaultValues2 = ["btn2_name": "Name your Btn 2"]
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: defaultValues2)
        let btn2value = ["btn2_onoff": true]
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: btn2value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the ViewController:

```
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(settingChanged(notification:)), name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)


    }
```

Then create an @objc func with the following:

```
    @objc func settingChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
     
        let btn1settings = userDefaults.bool(forKey: "btn1_onoff")


        if !btn1settings {
            btn1.isHidden = true
            btn1_label.isHidden = true
            btn1_count.isHidden = true

            
        }
        else {
            btn1.isHidden = false
            btn1_label.isHidden = false
            btn1_count.isHidden = false
        }
        let btn1name = userDefaults.string(forKey: "btn1_name")
        btn1_label.text = btn1name
```

This will update the app when the settings are updated in the "App Settings"